# AngularJS multiple ng-if are not being updated simultaneously. Why? How to fix?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I have two buttons to link and unlink a social sign-in provider.

```
<button class="btn btn-default" ng-if="!user.facebook" ng-click="link('facebook')">
  Link Facebook
</button>

<button class="btn btn-danger" ng-if="user.facebook" ng-click="unlink('facebook')">
  Unlink Facebook
</button>
```

Now whenever I hit **Unlink Facebook** for example, I send a POST request to the server, and then make a separate HTTP request to grab up-to-date user information right after unlinking (or linking) an account.

The problem that I don't understand is why there is almost a whole second delay before **Unlink Facebook** disappears.

I have two buttons. They cannot be active at the same time because the have the exact opposite conditions. If for example I have already linked an account, when I try to unlink it, as soon as the data is received, a new button appears **Link Facebook** (as it should) but it takes almost another second before **Unlink Facebook** button disappears.

**I am almost certain this has something to do with AngularJS lifecycle management. Is this possible to fix?**

### Update: This issue turns out to be this CSS property on `.btn` class: `transition: background-color 0.25s ease-out;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shouldn't happen, but it depends on the context (e.g. your `$watchers`, the complexity of your DOM etc).

In any case, since only one element should be present at a time, it would make more sense to use `ngSwitch` instead:

```
<div ng-switch="user.facebook">
    <button ng-click="user.facebook=true" ng-switch-default>
        Link Facebook
    </button>
    <button ng-click="user.facebook=false" ng-switch-when="true">
        Unlink Facebook
    </button>
</div>
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/3vpvwkk1/)**.

Comment: Thank you for the demo. I narrowed down the problem to Bootstrap 3. Removing `btn` classes seems to fix the issue. Now I need to ifnd out why does it happen.

Comment: @TwilightPonyInc.: I can't really reproduce the problem. If you could provide a fiddle or plunkr I would gladly look into it !